# R remotes package cannot install_github public github package on slow bandwidth

Tags: r, docker

I am struggling to install a public R package (140MB) during the docker image build with a rocker/TidyVerse base image.

I'm able to build the image on a fast internet connection (200Mbps) but struggling on 4Mbps

```
#11 687.2 The downloaded source packages are in
#11 687.2       ‘/tmp/Rtmpol4fiC/downloaded_packages’
#11 688.9 Downloading GitHub repo asgr/ProSpect@master
#11 748.8 Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
#11 748.8   download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/asgr/ProSpect/tarball/master' failed
#11 749.1 Skipping install of 'Rfits' from a github remote, the SHA1 (7050c11a) has not changed since last install.
#11 749.1   Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
#11 749.4 Skipping install of 'ProFit' from a github remote, the SHA1 (3ad5fa18) has not changed since last install.
#11 749.4   Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
#11 749.7 * checking for file ‘/tmp/Rtmpol4fiC/remotes6494ed363/kateharborne-SimSpin-857278e/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
#11 749.8 * preparing ‘SimSpin’:
#11 749.8 * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
#11 749.8 * cleaning src
#11 749.9 * installing the package to process help pages
#11 750.3       -----------------------------------
#11 750.3 ERROR: dependency ‘ProSpect’ is not available for package ‘SimSpin’
#11 750.3 * removing ‘/tmp/RtmpUvUFDh/Rinsta8b47db6258/SimSpin’
#11 750.3       -----------------------------------
#11 750.3 ERROR: package installation failed
#11 750.5 Error: Failed to install 'SimSpin' from GitHub:
#11 750.5   System command 'R' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed
#11 750.5 Execution halted
```

I've tried increasing the timeout, specifying the download method (libcurl), installing the offending package (ProSpect) first, but to no avail. Has anyone seen anything similar or have any suggestions? This is a consistent issue with remotes (and devtools) downloading on slower bandwidth from github.

```
# Dockerfile for R-based software (SimSpin)
#FROM rocker/r-ver:4.1.2
FROM rocker/tidyverse:4.0.2

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y xml2 openssl libhdf5-dev libfftw3-dev curl

RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes")'
RUN R -e 'options(timeout=9999999)'
RUN R -e 'options(download.file.method = "libcurl")'
RUN R -e 'Sys.setenv(R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS="true")'
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_github("asgr/ProSpect", ref="master")'
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_github("kateharborne/SimSpin", ref="master")'
```

---

UPDATE
I've narrowed it down to a problem with remotes:install_github on a slow connection (4Mbps download). I can't see how to configure to bypass this... (if i run the same install on 40Mbps+ it installs no problem, however I don't have access to that bandwidth all the time).

```
> remotes::install_github("kateharborne/SimSpin", ref="master")
Downloading GitHub repo kateharborne/SimSpin@master
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/kateharborne/SimSpin/tarball/master' failed
```

Answer (score 3):

What if instead of using `install_github` you cloned the repo a la:

```
git clone https://github.com/kateharborne/SimSpin
cd SimSpin
```

then used

```
devtools::install()
```

another option is to set the timeout option for `download.file` like:

```r
options(timeout=1000)
```

Comment: I've tried the timeout option, alas, no help. Thanks for your suggestion, a local clone would probably work - hopefully someone can suggest a workaround for remotes::install_github as it's blocking some workflows currently

Comment: You could also download the tarball from here and then install from that: https://github.com/kateharborne/SimSpin/archive/refs/tags/v2.2.0.tar.gz. That is a bit less messy than cloning the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done previously, but I'd really like to figure out how to get a remote repo installed with remotes or devtools on a slow connection

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install httr as well try this:
I think remotes uses httr, but doesn't install it in the dependencies for whatever reason.

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:4.0.2

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y xml2 openssl libhdf5-dev libfftw3-dev curl
RUN R -e 'install.packages("httr")'
RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes")'
RUN R -e 'options(timeout=9999999)'
RUN R -e 'options(download.file.method = "libcurl")'
RUN R -e 'Sys.setenv(R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS="true")'
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_github("asgr/ProSpect", ref="master")'
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_github("kateharborne/SimSpin", ref="master")'
```